# How to add a menu link to a menu programmatically?

Tags: routes, 8

I want to add a menu link to a menu programmatically. Here is my code

```
MenuLinkContent::create([
      'title' => 'Example link',
      'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node'],
      'menu_name' => 'main',
    ])->save();
```

But it gives me the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /var/www/drupal8/core/modules/menu_link_content/src/Plugin/Menu/MenuLinkContent.php on line 105
```

Is there any way to add menu links to a menu programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong namespace.
Use the following namespace

```
use Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent;
```

and then the following code will work.

```
MenuLinkContent::create([
      'title' => 'Example link',
      'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node'],
      'menu_name' => 'main',
    ])->save();
```

Comment: Where would one put this? IN the controller? Dot-module file?